# How do you remove focus from an SWT widget control (such as Text)?

Tags: java, swt

I know that we can use `setFocus()` to set a keyboard focus on a control object such as [text](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FText.html).

What can we do to remove the focus from the same object, reversing this function's effect?

Comment: You can force the focus onto another control.

Comment: @yks If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot remove the focus from a `Control`, i.e. *unfocus* it.

As @Baz suggests, you can transfer the focus to another control with `setFocus()` or `forceFocus()`. The latter gives focus to a `Control` even if it has the `SWT.NO_FOCUS` style, like `Label`s do.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove/transfer focus from a SWT Control(Text) in the following 2 ways:

- Set the focus on some other Control using the `setFocus()` method.
- You can disable the Control widget by using `setEnabled(false)` method, but this will deprive the widget of its functionality. Hence it's not recommended.

Comment: There is no `Control#requestFocus()` method in SWT and `setFocusable()` doesn't exist in SWT either.

Comment: Thanks @Rüdiger Herrmann for pointing out those errors. I may have got confused between SWT and Swing.. The answer has been updated